# Concurrent execution of large request across different IIS servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis

I have REST web API service in IIS which takes a collection of request objects. The user can enter more than 100 request objects. My service is deployed across 20 IIS servers.

I want to run this 100 request concurrently and then aggregate the result and send it back. This involves both I/O operation (calling to backend services for each request) and CPU bound operations (to compute few response elements).

when my controller receive the request can we split and share the request across all the 20 IIS servers available in the same or different machine to speed up the processing. Please suggest any option

Comment: Does your 100 or so request object depends on each other or any dependency like some request must execute before other request or all are same so you don't have to worry about order.

Comment: no its independent, we don't have to bother about ordering

Answer (score 1):

I can not provide detail implementation but you have to do following things.

There are many solution and I can suggest one of them.

**Solution 1**

1. Your one main application receive the request. ( Request with 100 objects or more than that).
2. Now here this application has information about your 20 other site or url. ( This urls can also stored in config or XML file)
3. Also you have to decided that each server should process one or more object at once. ( You can create such configuration and store in web.config )
4. Now based on your request you create httpClient to call RestApi and provide each data. Make sure you use Async model so you can take advantage of Async feature.
5. For example if I consider only one object per server and server configuration ( server url store in Array)

   ```
    int requestCnt = 0;
    foreach(var request in Requests)
    {
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     client.Url = Server[request % 20];
     client.PostAsync()
    }
   ```

Note : This is just sample thing so you have to work on detail implementation part.